# JSF/IceFaces Conditional Rendering

Tags: jsf, icefaces, el

I am using Icefaces to conditonally render a component but it cant pick up the boolean:

BeanCode:

```
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return true;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        if (isEmpty()){
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

IceFaces

<ice:panelGroup rendered="#{coverage.empty}"> //this doesnt work 
<ice:panelGroup rendered="#{coverage.count==0}"> //this does work
```

Error message:
Error Parsing: #{coverage.empty}

Why is IceFaces not recognising the boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, `empty` is a reserved word in Expression Language. It is indeed an operator.

It tests if an element is `null` or empty (for example, if your element is a `String`, it tests if his value is either `null` or `""`).

You can find many example of EL [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out empty is a reserved word in faces.