# jsf render component type?

Tags: jsf, datatable, dynamic-forms

I am creating an online survey application using JSF with IceFaces. The survey can have any number of questions. Each question can be any one of the types checkbox, radio button, textbox, etc., with multiple options.

Now I need to show the question one per page in jsf. I am fetching The question type, question, option list(opt1, opt2, opt3...) data from the db.

When user click on prev button, I need to go back to previous question.
When user click on next button, I need to go to next question. 
At the end, when user click on Submit button, need to store the survey data in the db.

How can I render the components based on the question type?
(If question type is checkbox means, I need to show checkbox. If question type is radio button means, I need to show radio button..)

How can I do this? Can anyone please help me on this?

If any example on this type please share me the link.

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319098/jsf-icefaces-conditional-rendering), it might help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `rendered` attribute. If the EL condition in the attiribute evaluates `true`, then the component will render HTML to the output, otherwise not.

So, assuming that you've a

```
public class Question {

    public enum Type { 
        SINGLE, MULTIPLE;
    }

    private Long id;
    private Type type;
    private String text;
    private List<Answer> answers;

    // ...
}
```

then you can use it as follows:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.questions}" var="question">
    <h:column>
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.answers[question.id]}" rendered="#{question.type == 'SINGLE'}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{question.answers}" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.answers[question.id]}" rendered="#{question.type == 'MULTIPLE'}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{question.answers}" />
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: can you tell me how you initiate the variable answers? I should do something like your example but when I tryied to set the value as you wrote"#{bean.answers[question.id]}" the page returns: "Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null"!

Comment: @Flippo: Just `answers = new ArrayList<Answer>()` on field or in (post) constructor.